# Oozie: Is there anything that needs to be done after placing an updated jar under lib folder?

Tags: oozie

I am trying to place an updated jar under lib path and removing the old jar. Unfortunately , I see the old logs in oozie console which were present in old jar. For confidential purpose I am unable to show logs here. But I am doing the below steps:

1. Replacing a jar (mycode.jar) under lib folder which is mentioned in workkflow.xml
2. Submitted the oozie job using `oozie job -oozie http://host -config job.properties -run`
3. When I see logs in console, I could see old jar(older version of mycode.jar) logs even if jar is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the `lib` directory in the oozie workflow application then you need not to do anything. The next execution of the workflow will automatically pick the new (updated) jar.

For updating the jars into share lib `/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_*/*` then after replacing the jar, you need to execute the following command to update the share lib into oozie server.

```
oozie admin -sharelibupdate
```

Hope this will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure issue is same I'll narrate what I was facing:

1. created a MapReduce JAR and placed it in lib folder.
2. Ran oozie(MapReduce action) job and picked the JAR as expected and ran fine.
3. I had some functionality changes in my code(JAR) so I added new log statements to make sure new JAR is being picked. Built the JAR and replaced the old JAR with newly built JAR in lib folder(hdfs)
4. Ran oozie job again, code from old JAR was executed because new log statements did not show up.

After few search I found following tips:

1. Clear the Yarn Cache: found this in HortonWorks site(https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/92339/how-to-clear-local-file-cache-and-user-cache-for-y.html)  - pasting content below for reference

Short Description:
To use different version jar file with same name, clear cache on all NodeManager hosts to prevent the application using old jar

```
a. Find out the cache location by checking the value of the yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs property 

< property >       
< name >yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs< /name>       
< value>/hadoop/yarn/local</value> 
< /property>
```

b. Remove filecache and usercache folder located inside the folders that is specified in yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs.

```
[yarn@node2 ~]$ cd /hadoop/yarn/local/ 

[yarn@node2 local]$ ls filecache  nmPrivate  spark_shuffle  usercache 

[yarn@node2 local]$ rm -rf filecache/ usercache/
```

c. Restart YARN service.

I was  unable to clear cache because I did not have the necessary access. Thus I followed below workaround

2. Rename the Package or class, since this package/class was written by me, I had the liberty to simply rename the class, thus in oozie when new Class name was looked up, automatically the new functionality was executed.

Option 2 may not be viable for many and the question remains open as to why oozie does not pick New JAR/Class.